# Сортировка чисел

Tags: php, mysql

При сортировке у меня сортируется, начиная с первых цифр, то есть 1, 11, 12, 13, 2, 21, 22 а нужно, чтобы 1, 2, 3, 4... 11, 12 и т.д. Вот мой запрос:

```
$myCmd = "SELECT * FROM dlpodrazdeleniya, dldoctor, dlSpec, dltime WHERE id='$cat' AND dldoctor.idPodr = dlpodrazdeleniya.idPodr AND dldoctor.SpecID =  dlSpec.SpecID AND dldoctor.DoctorID =  dltime.DoctorID ORDER BY dltime.Ychastok, dltime.DoctorID";
```

Сортирую я сначала по участкам, потом уже по врачам, но, главное, участки чтобы сортировались, как я описал выше.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже всего, такой результат сортировки из-за того, что поле текстовое, а не цифровое.

Answer (score 0):

Естественно это происходит из-за того, что вы сортируете именно строки! Как известно, для этого в "недрах" SQL применяется функция сортировки( будем называть её Compare ), которая работает аналогично функции, передаваемой в функцию сортировки **qSort** в С++. Выглядит она примерно так( пример! ):

```
int compare(char *a, char *b)
{
if(a>b) return 1; else if(a<b) return -1;
return 0;
}
```

Это примерная работа функции сравнения в C++ - `strcmp()`. Вот, какие результаты она выдаст( исходя из этого сделайте выводы ):

```
"123"<"132"
"aabbaa"<"aacwww" // Символ "с">"b"!
"bbw122">"bbw121"
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант

```
 ... ORDER BY dltime.Ychastok+1, dltime.DoctorID";
```